# Java "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java

I have this code that is doing my head in, i continue to receive the following errors upon compile. Any ideas?

```
8 errors found:
File: /Users//Desktop/Migration/BookingGUI.java  [line: 573]
Error: /Users//Desktop/Migration/BookingGUI.java:573: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable stakeholderExperience
location: class BookingGUI
File: /Users//Desktop/Migration/BookingGUI.java  [line: 576]
Error: /Users//Desktop/Migration/BookingGUI.java:576: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable stakeholderExpertise
location: class BookingGUI
```

The entire code is quite large so i don't want to post the whole thing... Basically i am trying to get this thing to load data from a text file once it is opened.

```html
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                str = sc.nextLine();
                // split line into parts by tab
                parts = str.split("\t");
                // if all details of stakeholder are present
                if(parts.length == 6) {
                    // get all details from parts string arrray of stakeholder
                    phone = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                    stakeholderName = parts[1];
                    stakeholderFamily = parts[2];
                    stakeholderEmail = parts[3];
                    stakeholder = null;
                    // if part of 4 string is not a dash then it is a 
                    // stakeholder
                    if(parts[5] != "-") {
                        stakeholderProjectName = parts[5];
                        stakeholder = new Client(phone, stakeholderName,
                            stakeholderFamily, stakeholderEmail, 
                            stakeholderIndustry, stakeholderProjectName);
                    // else if part 5 is not a dash then it is a classical
                    // stakeholder
                    } else if(parts[6] != "-") {
                        stakeholderExperience = parts[6];
                        stakeholder = new Developer(phone, stakeholderName,
                            stakeholderFamily, stakeholderEmail, 
                            stakeholderExpertise, stakeholderExperience);
                    // else it is a general stakeholder
                    } else {
                        stakeholder = new Stakeholder(phone, stakeholderName,
                            stakeholderFamily, stakeholderEmail);
                    }
                    // add stakeholder to stakeholders model and also to stakeholders in
                    // teams panel
                    stakeholderMdl.addElement(stakeholder);
                    stakeholderTeamMdl.addElement(stakeholder);
                }
            }
            sc.close();
```

Comment: The `stakeholderExperience` variable is not declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/BookingGUI.java:573: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable stakeholderExperience
location: class BookingGUI

This type of error occurs when the compiler cannot find an identifier. In this case, it cannot find the variable stakeholderExperience variable. Have you declared it in your BookingGUI class anywhere?